# What are the opening hours for Debrecen Airport?

Tags: europe, airports, hungary, opening-hours, central-europe

For the first time in my experience, sleepingatairports.com does not have the airport hours: https://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/debrecen-airport.htm

The hours also appear not to be given on the airport's website:
http://www.debrecenairport.com/index.php/allas-lista?lang=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://acukwik.com/Airport-Info/lhdc) the airport is closed from Midnight to 4am. Just because the Facebook site says "always open" on the side, doesn't mean the physical airport is open 24/7.

Answer (score 2):

They claim to be open 24/7 on their [Facebook site](https://de-de.facebook.com/debrecenairport/).

But just to be sure, give them a call on 
+36 52 518 800, write them in Facebook messenger or send an Email to office@debrecenairport.com.

Comment: Immediate reply from Faecbook Messenger: Köszönjük, hogy üzenetet küldtél nekünk. Igyekszünk minél gyorsabban reagálni a megkeresésekre, hamarosan jelentkezünk.
Repülőtéri segítség: info@debrecenairport.com
Jótékonysági futással kapcsolatos kérdések: info@debrunwayrun.hu 
Debrecen Airport

Comment: Probably written by a "bot". Will have to ask a Hungarian friend to call them.

Comment: Haha, maybe just write them an email

Comment: For reference, the Facebook Messenger reply says, "Thank you for contacting us. We strive to reply to requests as soon as possible; we will contact you shortly. Airport information: info@debrecenairport.com Questions about the charity run: info@debrunwayrun.hu"